Why is my JOIN not eliminating NULL values from the SUM?
I have 2 tables that are referenced in the following SQL ... when it runs I get an arithmetic overflow error:
DECLARE @IssueDate DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME = '9999-12-31 23:59:59';

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LPT.CustomerId, ISNULL(LPT.ExpiryDate, @MaxDate)) AS Id,
    LPT.CustomerId,
    LPT.ExpiryDate,
    SUM(LPT.PointsValue) AS PointsValue
FROM dbo.LoyaltyPointsTransaction AS LPT
JOIN dbo.Customer AS c ON c.CustomerId = LPT.CustomerId
WHERE (LPT.ExpiryDate IS NULL OR LPT.ExpiryDate > @IssueDate)
GROUP BY LPT.CustomerId,
        LPT.ExpiryDate
HAVING SUM(LPT.PointsValue) <> 0
ORDER BY SUM(LPT.PointsValue) DESC

The LoyaltyPointsTransaction has rows with large values that when summed could generate an overflow error but they all have a NULL CustomerId.
The Customer table only contains rows with a CustomerId (no NULLS), so shouldn't the JOIN have already filtered out the rows from LoyaltyPointsTransaction?
I can't understand why it's not filtering out the NULL rows before doing the SUM?

Presumbly, when you SUM(LPT.PointsValue)at some point it resolves to a value that is too large for the data type.

Also it's not just the final result that matters, but if at any point the value might overflow. For example, the final value in the following expression would be 1, but it results in an overflow, as 2147483647+1 is too large for an int: SELECT SUM(V.I) FROM (VALUES(2147483647),(1),(-2147483647))V(I);

Try: SUM(LPT.PointsValue * 1.0) perhaps? Or start outpaying some of those points

My point is that it shouldn't be considering summing the large values as the JOIN should eliminate the rows in which they exist as they've all got a NULL CustomerId

SQL Server doesn't always perform the operations in the order you prefer, for example it might decide it's faster to first GROUP LoyaltyPointsTransaction and build a Spool table and then join the customers. You can fix the SUM and see the query plan to understand what it does under the hood

As noted, the exact order of operations is not guaranteed and certain optimisations might cause things to be executed "out of order". Without the actual plan available, or a minimal reproducible example of the issue any suggestion I have as to why would be purely conjecture, but presumably for some reason SQL Server has decided it may be more efficient to first aggregate then remove nulls after aggregation. You might be able to avoid this by swapping out LTP.CustomerId for c.CustomerId in your select and group by, or by explicitly removing nulls with WHERE LTP.CustomerId IS NOT NULL

Thanks everyone ... I've amended the query to cast the value to a BIGINT and can see from the execution plan that it does indeed do an Index Scan on the LoyaltyPointsTransaction table with a Stream Aggregate before joining this to an Index Scan on the Customer table ... ergo it's summing up all the values first!
I've added an explicit AND LTP.CustomerId IS NOT NULL to the query to eliminate the problem.

Why use a join at all if you're not returning values from customer in the select?  If you're simply using it to filter records; use an exists or not exists in the where clause. My rule of thumb is don't join to it if you're not returning data to display.   It would be interesting to see if you added customer name to the select and group by if you need your LTP.CusotmerID is not null.  Putting the limit in the where clause makes it easier to understand/maintain as well as you're explicitly saying you're using it to filter data. and not hiding the limits on the join.

Thinking about this some more:  are you after only LoyaltyTransactionPoints for which a customer record exists? or those which are the customerID is not null?  Unless referential integrality is turned on those are not one in the same. Example: Customer 1234 could exist in the LTP table; but could have been deleted in Customer.  So if You look for not Null you'd get customer 1234 but if you look for exists in customer you'd not get 1234. So what are you after?

First, let's assume the tables are structured as follows, and then we will fill them with some synthetic data to ensure that errors occur.


CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer (
    CustomerId INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    
    CustomerName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Email NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    CreatedAt DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
);

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.LoyaltyPointsTransaction (
    TransactionId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    CustomerId INT  NULL,
    PointsValue INT NOT NULL, 
    ExpiryDate DATETIME NULL, 
    TransactionDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()  
   
);


INSERT INTO dbo.Customer (CustomerId, CustomerName, Email) VALUES 
(1, 'John Doe', 'john.doe@example.com'),
(2, 'Jane Smith', 'jane.smith@example.com');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.LoyaltyPointsTransaction (CustomerId, PointsValue, ExpiryDate) VALUES 
(1, 100, '2025-12-31'), 
(1, 50, NULL), 
(2, 200, '2023-12-31'), 
(2, -50, NULL),
(NULL, 2147483641, NULL),
(NULL, 2147483641, NULL); 
GO 5000



When we run the query again afterward, we will likely encounter the same error because I got the error. Now, let's take a look at the estimated query plan.

As seen, the query optimizer first retrieves the data from the LoyaltyPointsTransaction table and thinks that the best way is to join it with the Customer table after the aggregation. Since this is the case, the sum operation is performed without filtering out the NULL values in the Customer table, resulting in an arithmetic overflow error.
Yes, to resolve this issue, if we describe the optimizer to the join method, it will first join the Customer and LoyaltyPointsTransaction tables and then perform the aggregation.So the query will like this:


DECLARE @IssueDate DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME = '9999-12-31 23:59:59';

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LPT.CustomerId, ISNULL(LPT.ExpiryDate, @MaxDate)) AS Id,
    LPT.CustomerId,
    LPT.ExpiryDate,
    SUM(LPT.PointsValue) AS PointsValue
FROM dbo.LoyaltyPointsTransaction AS LPT
INNER LOOP JOIN dbo.Customer AS c ON c.CustomerId = LPT.CustomerId 

WHERE (LPT.ExpiryDate IS NULL OR LPT.ExpiryDate > @IssueDate)
GROUP BY LPT.CustomerId,
        LPT.ExpiryDate
HAVING SUM(LPT.PointsValue) <> 0
ORDER BY SUM(LPT.PointsValue) DESC



Now let's look at this query plan

